# Convert a sql result table to a spark R dataframe - Databricks

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, databricks, sparkr

I am running a notebook on databricks for an analysis. As part of that, I have a SQL query that produces a df which I want to convert to R df for further analysis. I tried saving that as a temp, but that doesnt work. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this effectively.

Comment: Show the code that you've tried & and error message if you got it

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
library(SparkR)
species <- sql("SELECT * FROM VALUES(1, 2) AS t1(c1, c2), VALUES(3, 4) AS t2(c3, c4);")
print(class(species))
df <- as.data.frame(species)
df

[1] "SparkDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SparkR"

  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  2  3  4
```